# what I am doing wrong with this boolean?

Tags: python, boolean

I am doing this code and for some reason when I add "or" or "and" and I ran  the code with the country "Puerto Rico" it do not show that is the correct answer. can anybody help this new Padawan programer? I know It might sound stupid  the code but well I have to start somewhere! thank you! and I tried my best to add the code here!

```
  user_country =input('Where do you from? ')
enter code here if (not user_country == 'Germany')  or ( user_country == 'Puerto Rico'):
enter code here print('You are not from Germany or Puerto Rico')
else:
  print('you are from Germany or Puerto Rico')
print('You qualify')
```

[image]

Comment: Please don't post code as images. Post code as properly formatted text.

Comment: The parentheses are wrong.  You are asking "if NOT Germany or YES Puerto Rico.".  You want `if not (user_country == 'Germany' or user_country == 'Puerto Rico'):`, or maybe `if user_country not in ('Germany', 'Puerto Rico'):`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's more succinct if you make use of the *in* keyword. For example...

```
if not user_country in {'Germany', 'Puerto Rico'}:
```

However, the flaw in your code can be resolved by:

```
if (not user_country == 'Germany') and (not user_country == 'Puerto Rico'):
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would do this:

`if user_country not in ['Germany', 'Puerto Rico']`

Answer (score 0):

You can rewrite like this,

```
check_counties = ["Puerto Rico", "Germany"]
if user_country not in check_counties:
    print('You are not from germany or Puerto Rico')
else:
    print('Qualify')
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code, when you enter "Puerto Rico", the second condition will be True and for "or" we need just one True, So the statement of "if" will be run. However second answer by @OldBill is good for you.
good luck.

here is complete code:

```
user_country = input('Where do you from? ')
if (not user_country == 'Germany') and ( not user_country == 'Puerto Rico'):
     print('You are not from Germany or Puerto Rico')
else:
     print('you are from Germany or Puerto Rico')
     print('You qualify')
```